# Delegate function to return value

Tags: vb.net, function, delegates

I am trying to get value from the delegate function. Basically I am trying to get the richboxtext line length from delegate function.

Here is my function

```
Private Delegate Function getrichlengthmain(ByVal TB As RichTextBox) As String

Private Function getrichlenghtdele(ByVal TB As RichTextBox) As string

        Return TB.Lines.Length


End Function
```

And I am calling it by

```
Dim d As getrichlengthmain

        d = AddressOf getrichlenghtdele

dim returnvalue as string

returnvalue = d.BeginInvoke(FstList,nothing,nothing)
```

2 problems in this code

1st problem

when I change the code from "returnvalue = d.BeginInvoke(FstList,nothing,nothing)" to "d.BeginInvoke(FstList,nothing,nothing)"

The cross-thread error popout while debuiging

2nd problem

How do I get the value from the function without getting any cross thread error.

Very thanks for your time and thanks in advance for solving it.

Comment: `BeginInvoke` is used to invoke a delegate asynchronously. Is that what you want to do? If it is, you cannot hope to get the result while the function may still be running. If it isn't, why are you using `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using the begininvoke because I want the function to safely get the lineslength from richtextbox. Is there any other way to safely get the line length from the richtextbox by using  function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing an error because the control you are trying to access was created on a different thread from the one you are accessing it on. This is a common mistake when developing threaded UI applications in .Net.

There are (at least) two ways to tackle the problem you have, the lazy way and the correct way. To solve this the lazy way, you simply stop the check for illegal cross-threading calls to controls from taking place by including this line of code somewhere in your UI component:

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```

A better way to deal with the problem is to ensure you code executes on the correct thread (therefore maintaining thread safety). One method of accomplishing this is described [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?498387-Accessing-Controls-from-Worker-Threads).

Comment: Setting `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` will make it so that the code sometimes works, depending on circumstances usually beyond the programmer's control. Sometimes can sometimes appear as "usually", other times as "rarely". I know you are not recommending it, but you do say it solves the problem, when it probably does not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False is not the good practice. It usually crash out my application. That is why I want to safely call the richtextbox to return its value. For this purpose I am using the delegate function but stuck to it. Wohoooo very thaaaaaaaaaaaaanks. Your given link solved my problem.